# NDK-BUILD Not recognized as a command (Windows)

Tags: android, android-ndk

I know there is lot's of this question already however half of the just redirect to other questions and the others either tell me to stuff i tried, none of which worked.

The problem is i have been following this [Tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/MartinFelis/love-android-sdl2/wiki/Building_L%C3%96VE_for_Android_-_Windows). And the last step tell's me to use the ndk-build command, however when i try to run it i get this

```
'ndk-build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

I know i have the environmental path thing set right, and i did install cygwin and i did add it manually to the android program. So i do not know what the issue is. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: use CLI/CMD window to invoke build. Set windows env VAR "NDK" to where you have the ndk installed. call $NDK/ndk-build

Comment: No idea what that means but i managed to solve it by installing the devel packages on cygwin and then instead of ndk-build i dragged the file into the window

Answer (score 3):

I also tried adding my ndk path to the System environment variables but the error was still there.

It worked for me by:

Opening command prompt and navigating to project
`c:\eclipse\workspace\myproject`

I then executed the ndk-build script from the android ndk folder

`c:\eclipse\workspace\myproject> c:\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build`

Comment: Is the `c:\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build` file a `.jar` file?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat, it is a windows build script. Just run it in your command prompt as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by setting my `NDK_HOME` environmental variable and updating my path.

The `$NDK_HOME` on OSX or Linux (or `%NDK_HOME%` on Windows) points to the Android NDK Home Directory.

Then updating the `PATH` variable to include that directory and appending `/build` to the end of the path which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about cygwin (it sometimes makes windows-user-friendly exceptions), but on a real linux there are at least 3 gotchas:

1) the current directory is not searched for executables (at least by default)

2) You have to set the execute permissions on the files you want to execute, `chmod a+x filename` sets that permission, `ls -l filename` shows the permissions.

3) The disk may be mounted so that execution is not allowed.

4) file names are case-sensitive

`which exefilename` shows the full path of a command -- that is, if the system recognizes *exefilename* as executable.

Does it work if you provide the full path?

Does it work is you use `source /full/path/to/ndk-build` ?